# Function will not run properly within a class but will run fine in a script on its own

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, asana, asana-api

I am having a challenging time finding references to my issue after searching. I have a function that performs an Asana task update. It  will run just fine when accessed in a simple script. I copied it into a class and now I get an invalid JSON error.

The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\johcalvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\johcalvi\Documents\Scripts\Sandbox\asana_reporting\LD_Reporting.py", line 934, in controlsTrainingKPI
    kpi.actualHrs()
  File "c:\Users\johcalvi\Documents\Scripts\Sandbox\asana_reporting\LD_Reporting.py", line 237, in actualHrs
    client.tasks.update_task(task_gid,
  File "C:\Users\johcalvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\asana\resources\gen\tasks.py", line 446, in update_task
    return self.client.put(path, params, **options)
  File "C:\Users\johcalvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\asana\client.py", line 216, in put
    return self.request('put', path, data=body, headers=headers, **options)
  File "C:\Users\johcalvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\asana\client.py", line 91, in request
    raise STATUS_MAP[response.status_code](response)
asana.error.InvalidRequestError: Invalid Request: Could not parse request data, invalid JSON
```

Example 1: the function that is defined within the class

```
def actualHrs(self):
    global df
    ar.asanaAuth()

    #Initial Queries for Actual Hours worked (workHrs) and Projected Hours(projectedHrs)
    self.workHrs = client.tasks.search_in_workspace(
                                       workspace = '8442528107068',
                                       params = {'projects.any':self.controlsTM,
                                       'due_on.after':'2021-12-31',
                                       'iterator_type':'items',
                                       'resource_type':'task',
                                       'opt_fields':['name','start_on',
                                       'due_on','assignee.name',
                                       'custom_fields.name',
                                       'custom_fields.display_value']} ,
                                        opt_pretty=True)
    #Build dataframe for actual hours worked data
    self.work_results = [self.x for self.x in self.workHrs]
    self.work_col_list = ['gid',
                          'Trainer',
                          'Task Scope',
                          'Hours_worked',
                          'Extra Hours',
                          'Barrier' ]

    json_normalize(self.work_results)
    self.dic_flattened=[flatten(self.d) for self.d in self.work_results]
    df = pd.DataFrame(self.dic_flattened)

    #Clean up dataFrame
    df = df.rename(columns = {'assignee_name':'Trainer',
                              'custom_fields_3_display_value':'Task Scope',
                              'custom_fields_4_display_value':'Hours_worked',
                              'custom_fields_5_display_value':'Barrier',
                              'custom_fields_12_display_value':'Extra Hours',
                              'due_on':'Due',
                              'start_on':'Start'
                             })
    #Set dataType for calculated fields
    df['Due'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due'])
    df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
    df['Hours_worked'] = df['Hours_worked'].astype(float, errors= 'raise')
    df['Extra Hours'] = df['Extra Hours'].astype(float, errors = 'raise' )

    #Calculate Extra Hours_worked (>8 in a day)
    df['Extra Hours'] =  df['Hours_worked'] - 8
    df['Extra Hours'] = np.where(df['Extra Hours'] < 0, 0, df['Extra Hours'])

    df= df.drop(columns= [col for col in df if col not in self.work_col_list]).fillna(value = np.nan).reindex(columns = self.work_col_list)

    #For  troubleshooting data mismatch
    df.to_csv('data_csv.csv')

    #Update Asana calculated fields for  Extra Hours,
    for self.index, self.row in df.iterrows():
        task_gid=self.row['gid']

        #Calculate % Utilization based on Proj_Hours/Total Avail monthly Hours
        # per trainer for a 30 day outlook (206hrs per month per trainer)

        ## Calculate Extra_Hours based on any over 9 in a day
        extra_hrs_val =self.row['Hours_worked']-9

        if extra_hrs_val <0 :
            extra_hrs_val = 0
        else:
            extra_hrs_val = extra_hrs_val

        print('Updating Extra Hours')

        client.tasks.update_task(task_gid,
                                 params = {'notes':'Task automatically updated',
                                           'custom_fields':{'1201357453126283':
                                                            extra_hrs_val}
                                          },
                                 opt_pretty=False
                                 )

    return df
```

Example 2 is from the test that I ran in a separate script:

```
def actualHrs():
    global df
    asanaAuth()

    #Initial Queries for Actual Hours worked (workHrs) and Projected Hours(projectedHrs)
    workHrs = client.tasks.search_in_workspace(
                                    workspace = '8442528107068',
                                    params = {'projects.any':controlsTM,
                                             'due_on.after':'2021-12-31',
                                             'iterator_type':'items',
                                             'resource_type':'task',
                                             'opt_fields':['name','start_on',
                                             'due_on','assignee.name',
                                             'custom_fields.name',
                                             'custom_fields.display_value']} ,
                                             opt_pretty=True)
    #Build dataframe for actual hours worked data
    work_results = [x for x in workHrs]
    work_col_list = ['gid','Trainer',
                     'Task Scope',
                     'Hours_worked',
                     'Extra Hours',
                     'Barrier' ]

    json_normalize(work_results)
    dic_flattened=[flatten(d) for d in work_results]
    df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)

    #Clean up dataFrame
    df = df.rename(columns = {'assignee_name':'Trainer',
                              'custom_fields_3_display_value':'Task Scope',
                              'custom_fields_4_display_value':'Hours_worked',
                              'custom_fields_5_display_value':'Barrier',
                              'custom_fields_12_display_value':'Extra Hours',
                              'due_on':'Due',
                              'start_on':'Start'
                             })
    #Set dataType for calculated fields
    df['Due'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due'])
    df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
    df['Hours_worked'] = df['Hours_worked'].astype(float, errors= 'raise')
    df['Extra Hours'] = df['Extra Hours'].astype(float, errors = 'raise' )

    #Calculate Extra Hours_worked (>8 in a day)
    df['Extra Hours'] =  df['Hours_worked'] - 8
    df['Extra Hours'] = np.where(df['Extra Hours'] < 0, 0, df['Extra Hours'])

    df= df.drop(columns= [col for col in df if col not in work_col_list]).fillna(value = np.nan).reindex(columns = work_col_list)

    #For troubleshooting data mismatch
    df.to_csv('data_csv.csv')

    #Update Asana calculated fields for Projected Hours, Extra Hours, and % Utilization
    for index,  row in  df.iterrows():
        task_gid= row['gid']

        ## Calculate Extra Hours :
        extra_hrs_val = row['Hours_worked']-9
        if  extra_hrs_val <0 :
            extra_hrs_val = 0
        else:
            extra_hrs_val =  extra_hrs_val

        print('Updating Asana')
        print(task_gid)
        client.tasks.update_task(task_gid,
                                 {'notes':'Task automatically updated',
                                 'custom_fields': {'1201357453126283': extra_hrs_val}
                                 },
                                 opt_pretty=False
                                )

    return df
```

For all I know I am chasing my tail due to something simple as I am still pretty new to this.

Comment: What did you add all the `self`s to your code?  You only need self for those variables that you're actually planning on using outside the class.  Why does this method need to be inside the class in the first place?

Comment: The selfs are clearly a matter of me not truly understanding their use, thank you for that clarification. As far as why I have it in a class is the simple fact that this is part of a larger app and I have broken up sections of it into classes mostly because I figured it would help with organization but also because I was hoping to at least try and sort out how it all works.

Comment: If you're just moving a function into a class, but not really using any of that class's instances, just copy the code as is and mark it as `@staticmethod`.  You don't even need to add `self` as an argument.    In Python, every file is a separate namespace.  So there is less of a need to put every function into a class to keep things clean.

Comment: @FrankYellin I see what you are saying. I will give that a shot.  I can definitely see how I made things more challenging than they need to be

Comment: You should include the full traceback in your question to help identify where the problem is.

Comment: @martineau I added the traceback as requested

Comment: @martineau I will get the hang of this hopefully sooner rather than later. Thank you again

Comment: Hmm, the problem has something to do with the Asana calculated fields and the `client.tasks` global variable and causing it to make a bad "request". Since I know nothing about Aasana reporting, I can't be any more specific. Generally speaking debugging when global variables are involved can be difficult — which is why they should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @martineau I understand what you are saying. IN order to maybe shed a little light on the subject These functions are identical with the exception that one was brought into a class. I removed it from the class and I am getting the same issue. I will look at the client connection for the request. Thanks for the direction

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the sound advice on both my potential issue as well as helping to improve my style...It turns out that I was formatting null values as nan when using the pd.fillna method in the function in question which was causing the JSON structure to fail. After reformatting it to a value of 0 all works as designed.  I think I had an errant undo or a copy/paste error